# jQuery each loop with jayq and ClojureScript

Tags: jquery, clojurescript

I'm trying to do an each loop over some elements in ClojureScript using jayq, but I'm not having any success. I keep getting "Invalid arity: 1" at run-time.

The function is checking a bunch of boxes based on the checked value of a single box (think of a "check all" feature). The `toggle-all-checkboxes` function as called when they click that "check all" box:

```
(ns foo.events
  (:use [jayq.core :only 
    [$ is prop]]))

(defn toggle-all-checkboxes [event]
  (let [checked (is ($ (.-target event)) ":checked")]
    (.each ($ "td.checkbox-col input")
      (fn [_ checkbox] (
        (prop ($ checkbox) "checked" checked))))))
```

This actually checks the first box returned by `($ "td.checkbox-col input")`, but then gets the "Invalid arity" error afterwards.

I'm guessing since jayq doesn't have `each`, there's probably an idiomatic way of doing this, but I'm having trouble locating it. I couldn't use `map` because of what `($ "td.checkbox-col input")` returns (not an array, exactly).

Answer (score 2):

I created a generic solution. Not sure if it's the best, but it gets the job done:

Generic function that's like [.each in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
(defn jq-each [selector each-fn]
  (let [elements (js->clj ($ selector))]
    (dotimes [el-num (count elements)]
      (each-fn el-num (nth elements el-num)))))
```

And my example of usage:

```
(defn toggle-all-checkboxes [event]
  (let [checked (is ($ (.-target event)) ":checked")]
    (jq-each 
      "td.checkbox-col input" 
      (fn [i checkbox]
        (prop ($ checkbox) "checked" checked)))))
```

The each function is like what we have in jQuery: an index and the currently iterated element.